# Layout combinators in wxhaskell

Tags: user-interface, haskell, wxhaskell

I'm trying to fill text entries to fill the whole width, which works fine if the entries are put directly to the frame, but if they're put in to a panel, they revert to their default size. Also the 'boxed' layout combinator text disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

main = start gui

gui = do
  f <- frame []
  p <- panel f []
  xcoord <- entry p []
  ycoord <- entry p []
  set p [layout := fill $ boxed "foo" $
      grid 5 5 [
          [floatRight $ label "x   coordinate", hfill $ widget xcoord]
        , [floatRight $ label "y coordinate", hfill $ widget ycoord]
      ]
    ]
  set f [layout := fill $ container p glue]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're specifying the layout of p in the `set p [layout := ...` statement and then throwing it away with the `container p glue` usage.

(`container`'s second parameter is a layout for the container. `glue` is a layout, but not a sensible one for a panel.)

You should either (simplest) replace `container p glue` with `widget p` like this:

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

main = start gui

gui = do
  f <- frame []
  p <- panel f []
  xcoord <- entry p []
  ycoord <- entry p []
  set p [layout := boxed "foo" $
      grid 5 5 [
          [floatRight $ label "x   coordinate", hfill $ widget xcoord]
        , [floatRight $ label "y coordinate", hfill $ widget ycoord]
      ]
    ]
  set f [layout := fill $ widget p]
```

or move all your layout code into the container expresssion at the end:

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

main = start gui

gui = do
  f <- frame []
  p <- panel f []
  xcoord <- entry p []
  ycoord <- entry p []
  set f [layout := fill $ container p $ boxed "foo" $
      grid 5 5 [
          [floatRight $ label "x   coordinate", hfill $ widget xcoord]
        , [floatRight $ label "y coordinate", hfill $ widget ycoord]
      ]]
```

but I prefer the first one, because it feels cleaner to me and seems easier to add more stuff to your main frame `f` later.